After increasing disk size from fdisk the partition is showing corrupted
After booting the server went in Grub rescue mode.
I tried to find the file and found:

I tried to boot with Ubuntu ISO and checked the partition as shown below.
The file required is /dev/sda1 , /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda4 which is showing as corrupted.

I tried mounting /dev/sda2 got an error as shown below. Is there any to repair the partition?
Results of lsblk :

Results of mount :


Can you put the partition sizes back to their original sizes?  If you had increased the partition on the "right", the filesystem would still be intact, although probably no larger until resize2fs gets run( don't remember if gparted does that for you automatically). partitions extended on the "left" have lost the filesystem, but the data is still intact.
